# Jquery Using Ajax to build an Array in certain format

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to build an array from an AJAX call from a database.

The array needs to be in the following format.

```
var events = [
  {
    date: 'Q1 - 2018',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
  },
  {
    date: 'Q2 - 2018',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
  },
  {
    date: 'Q3 - 2018',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
  },
  {
    date: 'Q4 - 2018',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
  }
];
```

Currently as part of my success AJAX return function I have the following

```
var events = [];
var parsed = JSON.parse(ef1.d);
  if (Object.keys(parsed).length > 0) {
  $.each(parsed, function (idx, obj) {
      events.push("date: '" + obj.stage + "', content: '" + obj.text + "'");
  });
}
```

But the timelime that I'm using is not able to read it
BTW - I am building a timeline - https://github.com/stefanomarra/jquery-roadmap

Idea's ???, I may just be missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

OK figured it out - I was looking too hard at it.

Changed to Array push to the following

```
events.push({ date: obj.stage, content: obj.text})
```

Live and Learn :)